# How exclude folder index with Regex in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

Each time I open new generated project by yeoman,webstorm run indexing on node_modules folder make my mac book pro(with SSD) heat,everything is slow down by that.
Is there any way to add a global Regex list of folders to exclude from index?